# Passing a parameter of foreign key while filtering objects in django

Tags: django

I am having a django website. I have the following models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    type=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

This is my url for the products page:

```
path("products/<str:type>/",views.category,name="category"),
```

What I am wanting to do is that I want to display the products of the type passed in url.This is my views.py:

```
def category(request,type):
    prods=Product.objects.filter(category.type=type)
    context = {
        'categories':Category.objects.all(),
        'prods' : prods,
    }    
    return render(request,"category.html",context)
```

but this is giving me error that I need to use == in filter. and if I just use `prods=Product.objects.filter(category=type)` then it asks for the category id from the category model rather than the type of category. What can be a fix to that such that if i pass leather in filter (in url as type) then only the products with category.type= leather show up in my template.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the below one.

```
prods=Product.objects.filter(category__type=type)
```